# How to export sql server table data to bcp files in .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, file

I want to develop a web application utility that's needs to be download table data as bcp's , table structure and stored procedures as sql from sql server database. I have a idea of downloading sp's, but no idea on downloading and uploading bcp files from and to sql server DB, can we develop such utility using .Net.

Comment: Why? You get the same things with a simple backup. The `bcp` utility exports data to delimited files. It's not a database scripting tool. Are you trying to immitate the script dumping found on other databases? Again, why? A backup contains the same data while being a lot smaller and a **lot** faster to create and restore

Comment: Yes, I want to back up whole sql server data as tables and stored procedures.

Comment: Why this question then? Why don't you execute a BACKUP command? You can execute a BACKUP command programmatically using the [SQL Server Management Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx) but in the end, the same BACKUP command will be sent to the server

Comment: Utility will not be use not only for me, for all developers in my company, it should be usable. Running command every time , its wastage of time, so we need to maintain UI to download the scripts and data from sql server

Comment: That comment doesn't explain anything. First, the UI you mentioned exists - it's SSMS. Second, even if you want to create a web page to do this, for whatever reason (not the one you mentioned), it's still a backup. Take a backup and store it on a network share. You can use SSMS for this too

Comment: Why would developers want to generate backups of a database? Are you using the backups as a form of versioning? Have you looked at [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx)? Perhaps you need a database project, not a backup. You can easily import an existing database *and* use version control eg with git

Comment: Versioning SQL project is fine, but if I am not wrong  that project won't handle table data, that handle only table and SP scripts ? @PanagiotisKanavos